# Как поменять язык в vue-i18n?

Tags: vue.js, i18n

С помощью **vue add i18n**  добавил в только что созданный проект i18n. Файлы  **i18n.js**  и **main.js**  не трогал. В компоненте пытаюсь изменить язык как в видео [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHpfBNtwZVs) , но выдаёт ошибку. Причём если руками в **i18n.js** меняю **locale** то всё работает.

**Ошибка:**

> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:218 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading '$i18n')
> at Proxy.changeLocal (Header.vue?0418:14:1)
> at Object.onClick._cache.._cache. (Header.vue?0418:2:1)
> at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:155:1)
> at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:164:1)
> at HTMLDivElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:366:1)

**i18n.js**

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

function loadLocaleMessages() {
    const locales = require.context(
        './locales',
        true,
        /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i
    );
    const messages = {};
    locales.keys().forEach((key) => {
        const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i);
        if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
            const locale = matched[1];
            messages[locale] = locales(key).default;
        }
    });
    return messages;
}

export default createI18n({
    sync: true,
    locale: 'ru',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
});
```

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import i18n from './i18n'

createApp(App).use(i18n).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

**Компонент , где хочу поменять язык**

```
<template>
    <div class="header" @click="changeLocal()">
        {{ $t('message') }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Header',
    setup() {
        const changeLocal = () => {
            this.$i18n.locale = 'en';
        };
        return { changeLocal };
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня, в последнем Vue3 ts приложении устроено вот так.
Переменная `locale` прокинута в v-model `<input type="radio">`.
Всё отлично работает.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { locale } = useI18n();

    return {
      locale,
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Круто , сработало. А где ты узнал что именно так нужно его использовать. И в документации и в интернете все используют this.$i18n.locale = 'en'

Comment: Уже и не вспомнить :)